# I want to move /home from one partition to another. How do I go about doing this?

Tags: partition, home

I recently removed Windows from my computer which left me with a lot of unallocated space (which I later formatted to ext4). So I was wondering if it is possible to "copy" the /home partition from sda11 to sda5 as shown in the image here from Gparted.
[image: Partitions on my computer]

I am very new to this, so if someone can give me a detailed procedure to follow, or point me to where I could find one, I will be extremely grateful.

Comment: Before anything major like this, make sure your backups are up to date. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving
But you also can use it as a data partition. I keep /home inside / (root) and /home is about 3GB, but have all data in linked folders from a data partition. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: @oldfred why not make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it would be a good idea not to use `sda5` directly but make it an LVM PV (`pvcreate`), create an LVM VG for it (`vgcreate`) and create an LVM LV `home` in that VG (`lvreate`). That makes later changes in size much easier and has advatages for backups.

However you do it:

- Mount the formatted target block device somewhere, e.g. `/mnt/tmp`
- Abort all processes which use `/home` (to be on the safe side you can run `umount /home && mount /home`)
- copy the data from the old filesystem to the new: `cp -a /home/. /mnt/tmp`
- change the entry for `/home` in `/etc/fstab` from the old to the new block device (or UUID, see `blkid`)
- unmount the old filesystem: `umount /home`
- mount the new filesystem: `mount /home`
- check that it worked: `df -h /home`

Comment: LVM is a major change and is more advanced use of Volumes. While offering some advantages, you really need to do it as a new install & restore all data from backups.

Comment: I saw a few other sources (including other answers) which asked me to use rsync and not cp. Do both do the job?

Comment: @VBtheHun `rsync` was made for comparing two directories or directory trees and eliminate the differences (or some of them). It was especially made for doing this over a network. In that case it does a much better job than `scp`/`cp`. But in case of an empty target directory none of the `rsync` features is relevant (unless the procedure is interrupted). So in your case `rsync` is at least not better than `cp`.

Comment: @HaukeLaging can confirm that using `cp` in lieu of `rsync` worked absolutely fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## If you can delete /dev/sda5 (it seems empty/unused?)

If that is true, then there's a quite simple way to do it with the Gparted UI:

1. delete /dev/sda5
2. Move the neighbouring /dev/sda8 to the front (where sda5 was located)
3. move+enlarge /dev/sda11 as you please

The system will have to physically move the ~27GB of sda5 (/) and possibly also the 55GB of sda11 (/home), so depending on your disk that might take some hours.

## Otherwise

You'd need a terminal to do the trick. Either copy the whole sda11 partition over sda5 with a `dd` like this:

```
dd if=/dev/sda11 of=/dev/sda5 bs=1M
```

... or assign /dev/sda5 some mountpoint and copy the data with rsync or whatever file manager you prefer (just be careful to use rsync's `-an` option to keep access rights). When done, change remove sda11's mountpoint and change sda5 to /home .

Comment: Do not use dd on gpt partitions, only on a full drive. And dd generally not best tool. The cp -a or rsync with various parameters are better options if copying data. See post #12 by author of gdisk. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680929&page=2

Comment: @oldfred "Do not use dd on gpt partitions, only on a full drive." What gave you that strange idea...?

Comment: The author of gdisk years ago said not to use dd on a gpt partition. Do not use dd to copy partition with gpt due to unique guids & UUIDs post #12
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1680929  The GUID is stored in the primary partition table, backup partition table & partition. It may be possible to fix GUID with gdisk. You can use dd to copy an entrire drive, but generally dd is not the safest (nickname Data Destroyer) or best tool (copies empty space).

Answer (score 0):

Before anything major like this, make sure your backups are up to date.

To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions.

help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

But you also can use it as a data partition.
I keep /home inside / (root) and /home is about 3GB, but have all data in linked folders from a data partition. Does not have to be a second drive as these examples show. Just any other partition.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk